# Checking the last element of multiple lists

Tags: python, list, function

How can i check the last letter in a string that is the last element of multiple lists? I want to see if the last element of eight different lists are the same, if they are not i want to throw out an error and let the user try again. The point of the function i want to make is that if there are no lists with this last element the function should print something like ("Does not") As you can see in the example this should work because e is present as the last element in "Tie" and "he".

```
pile1=["vapor","Tie"]
pile2=["stone","he"]
pile3=["glass","sto"]

piles=pile1,pile2,pile3
def lose():
    for pile in piles:
        #here it should go through the last element and last letter in the string of everything in bunke
            print("Does not work")
lose()
```

Comment: Er..., `e` is last letter of last word of `pile1` and `pile2` but not for `pile3`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a list of all last letter of all last word of each pile then create a `set` with this list. Now, if the length of this `set` is not 1 there are, at least, two different letters:

```
if len(set([pile[-1][-1] for pile in piles if len(pile)])) > 1:
    print('Does not')

# Output:
Does not
```

In your example:

```
>>> [pile[-1][-1] for pile in piles if len(pile)]
['e', 'e', 'o']

>>> set([pile[-1][-1] for pile in piles if len(pile)])
{'e', 'o'}
```

Comment: its only the last letter that need so be the same, so should be pile[-1][-1] i think

Comment: In his case, it should be more `pile[-1][-1]`, since he wants to compare last letters

Comment: thanks for the great reply. How would i alter this so it works if some of the lists are empty?

Comment: @Sondre. I updated my answer. I appended `if len(pile)` to filter empty lists.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing! This refers to the indexing of characters

String, technically, is a list of characters. So this works not only for accessing whole elements of lists, but characters of String.

Try out this code and see what it gives you. You may need to alter it, if I have misunderstood the specifics.

```
for pile in piles:
    print(pile[-1][-1])
```

Comment: [0] accesses first element; since slicing is 0-indexed. So [-1] will access the last.

Comment: This worked very well for the intended purpose. But what should i do if i want to alter it to print ("does not work") when the last element is not printed more than one time? my output varies depending on my program so one time something is not repeated i want to get an error message.

Comment: Scratch my last comment. I wanna make a line that checks if the [-1][-1] is repeated or not. If the last is not repeated in any lists, i then want my error message.

Comment: `last_idx = pile[-1][-1]` … `for idx, pile in enumerate(piles): if last_idx == idx: … ` @Sondre